# which objc library support redis 2.6, eval and script?

Tags: objective-c, redis, eval

which objc library can support redis 2.6's command,eval script?
the ObjCHiredis can't do these.

--------

COMPLETE
commandArgv method can solve this question.
for example:
commandArgv:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"eval","YOURSCRIPT",nil]
commandArgv:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"script",@"load", @"YOURSCRIPT",nil]